# Add two lists of integers together into a 3rd list?

Tags: python, list

for example

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[1,2,3,4,5]
..
list3=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

I've already tried something, but it pops me a message that says: out of range". here is my code:

```
for i in range(mikos):
    lista3[i]=lista1[i]+lista2[i]

print(lista3)

#'mikos' is the number of elements in each list
```

Comment: How have you defined lista3 before the `for` loop?  It seems like it probably doesn't have 5 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do:

```
from operator import add
map(add, list1, list2)
```

Another would be:

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

And yet another one is

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a loop:

```
lista3 = [x+y for x,y in zip(lista1, lista2)]
```

Comment: Might want to use `izip_longest()` with a `fillvalue=0` argument to handle lists of differing lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple approach is:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[1,2,3,4,5]    
list3 = []    
mikos = len(list1)

for i in range(mikos):
    list3.append(list1[i]+list2[i])

print(list3)
```

Comment: `mikos` means something like `length` in English.. for those who wonder as I did.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I think that the OP looks rather for a simple solution than a comprehension expression that is very nice but somewhat harder to use for a beginner. (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)